# Is there a way to programmatically connect to a remote server from Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, finder

Is there an Coca/obj-C API call to mimic the "Connect to Server" action in Finder?  It's possible with Automater, so it seems like Finder has a hook somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out there's an old Carbon function (can't find a Cocoa equivalent) called `FSMountServerVolumeSync` which does what I was looking for.  You can supply and `smb://` URL and login credentials.

[File Manager Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/File_Manager/Reference/reference.html)

```
OSStatus FSMountServerVolumeSync (
  CFURLRef url,
  CFURLRef mountDir,
  CFStringRef user,
  CFStringRef password,
  FSVolumeRefNum *mountedVolumeRefNum,
  OptionBits flags
);
```

Answer (score 3):

An easy way is to just run some applescript code. I'll show you 2 choices. This first one is the standard way to show that Finder window from applescript.

```
NSString* cmd = @"choose URL";
```

The resulting window is bare-bones though, so you can actually open the Finder's window with this command...

```
NSString* cmd = @"tell application \"Finder\" to activate\ndelay 0.2\ntell application \"System Events\" to keystroke \"k\" using command down";
```

After choosing either of the "cmd" strings, you can execute that applescript code with this...

```
NSAppleScript* theScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:cmd];
[theScript executeAndReturnError:nil];
[theScript release];
```

Comment: This works, but your script mistyped "application" after "delay 0.2".

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the *best* way, but can't you just use `mount`?

Comment: For a remote server (like `smb://`)? I'm pretty sure `mount` is for local devices only.

Comment: Works on Linux at least - you specify it as //server.name/share/path/to/folder